# Getting the users email - Google+ Sign In

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-oauth

I am using [G+ Sign In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/) with JavaScript to let users sign in to a site. I want to display the email that they sign in with, and put it on the site to make sure the user knows they're logged in. I think it might be a button attribute, but all of the links to the button attribute page (such as [this](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#sign-in_button_attributes)) link to the overview of the G+ Sign In.

HTML:

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="26589332632-6ueke39kltk5cejpk5sdiu1i4i89m45a.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
  </span>
</span>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
 })();
```

P.S. This doesn't seem to show in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:
 data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
to
 data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email">
as documented here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes

This adds the scope that controls access to the user's email address to your code.

Comment: would I use `dada-scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'` or just `data-scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'`? what i mean is would I add both of the url's or just the last one?

Comment: You should use both URLs.

Comment: Now how do I retrieve the email and display it on the page?

Comment: Are you still there? Have you given up?

Comment: Make a call to people.get() as described here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get and here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript

Comment: I don't really know how to process this. I don't know how to retrieve the email out of all of _that_. Sorry, I'm kinda new to JSON

Comment: You should make the call as described here: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-javascript/blob/master/index.html#L156

You can learn how to use the Javascript API's client library here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples

Comment: I have added a span #mail that is supposed to hold the email with: `var email = gapi.client.plus.people.get({'userId' : 'me'}); $('#mail').html(email);` the email doesn't show in the span.

Comment: You have to call `execute` on the request first and set the value of #mail in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

On your callback function you can do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var profile, email;

        function loginFinishedCallback(authResult) {
            if (authResult) {
                if (authResult['error'] == undefined){
                    gapi.client.load('plus','v1', loadProfile);  // Trigger request to get the email address.
                } else {
                    console.log('An error occurred');
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Empty authResult');  // Something went wrong
            }
        }

        /**
         * Uses the JavaScript API to request the user's profile, which includes
         * their basic information.
         */
        function loadProfile(){
            var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get( {'userId' : 'me'} );
            request.execute(loadProfileCallback);
        }

        function loadProfileCallback(obj) {
            profile = obj;
            email = obj['emails'].filter(function(v) {
                return v.type === 'account'; // Filter out the primary email
            })[0].value; // get the email from the filtered results, should always be defined.
            $('#name').html(email);
        }
 </script>
```